# Enumerate two python lists simultaneously?

Tags: python, list

How do I enumerate two lists of equal length simultaneously?
I am sure there must be a more pythonic way to do the following:

```
for index, value1 in enumerate(data1):
    print index, value1 + data2[index]
```

I want to use the index and data1[index] and data2[index] inside the for loop.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) for both Python2 and Python3:

```
for index, (value1, value2) in enumerate(zip(data1, data2)):
    print(index, value1 + value2)  # for Python 2 use: `print index, value1 + value2` (no braces)
```

Note that `zip` runs only up to the shorter of the two lists(not a problem for equal length lists), but,  in case of unequal length lists if you want to traverse the whole list then use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: thanks this solved `zip(data1, data2).index(val1, val2)`

Answer (score 17):

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(data1, data2)):
```

In Python 2.x, you might want to use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`, esp. for very long lists.

Comment: Does anyone else hate that `enumerate` is nine characters long?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: now that you mention it, it could have been named `enum` to be consistent with `len` and `str`.

Comment: @jamylak: true, so maybe it should be named `enu` ;)

Comment: @larsmans yeah that would fit in with `zip` and `map`! should make a request for Python 4 ;) ;)

Comment: @jamylak: don't forget to request `range` → `rng` as well to make a stronger case. Oh, and `rpr`.

Comment: @larsmans `chain.from_iterable` → `chain.fi` and then we should make `input()` into `<>` and change `print` to `say` (you know to make up for the extra 2 characters I have to type each time I use Py3)

Comment: @jamylak: `re.match` → `~`. Feel like forking Python to start the Pthn prg lng?

Comment: @larsmans of course, but I'm afraid that once I start it I won't be able to go back...

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Readability first! - enum() was considered but rejected:  [PEP 279](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/)

Answer (score 11):

```
from itertools import count

for index, value1, value2 in zip(count(), data1, data2):
    print(index, value1, value2)
```

Source: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-use-pythons-enumerate-and-zip-to/#c2603

Answer (score 2):

Althought this is not very clear what you look for,

```
>>> data1 = [3,4,5,7]
>>> data2 = [4,6,8,9]
>>> for index, value in enumerate(zip(data1, data2)):
    print index, value[0]+value[1]


0 7
1 10
2 13
3 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been mentioned that the length are equal,

```
for l in range(0, len(a)):
   print a[l], b[l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to use `zip`:

```
   >>> for x in zip([1,2], [3,4]):
    ...     print x
    ... 
    (1, 3)
    (2, 4)
```

Comment: The index is need inside the loop too.