# mplcursors interactivity with endpoints of scatterplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Universe': ['Darvel', 'MC', 'MC', 'Darvel', 'MC', 'Other', 'Darvel'],
     'Value': [10, 11, 13, 12, 9, 7, 10],
     'Upper': [12.5, 11.3, 15.4, 12.2, 13.1, 8.8, 11.5],
     'Lower': [4.5, 9.6, 11.8, 6, 6.5, 5, 8]})
df['UpperError'] = df['Upper'] - df['Value']
df['LowerError'] = df['Value'] - df['Lower']

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, universe in enumerate(df['Universe'].unique()):
    to_plot = df[df['Universe'] == universe]
    ax.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot['Value'], s=16, c=colors[i])
    error = to_plot[['LowerError', 'UpperError']].transpose().to_numpy()
    ax.errorbar(to_plot.index, to_plot['Value'], yerr=error, fmt='o',
                markersize=0, capsize=6, color=colors[i])
    ax.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot['Upper'], c='w', zorder=-1)
    ax.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot['Lower'], c='w', zorder=-1)
    
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)

plt.show()
```

This does most of what I want, but I want the following changes.

1. I do not want the mplcursors cursor to interact with the errorbars, but just the scatter plots, including the invisible scatterplots on top and bottom of the errorbars.
2. I just want the y value to show. For example, the first bar should say "12.5" on the top, "10.0" in the middle, and "4.5" on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have mplcursors only interact with some elements, a list of those elements can be given as the first parameter to `mplcursors.cursor()`. The list could be built from the return values of the calls to `ax.scatter`.

To modify the annotation text shown, a custom function can be connected. In the example below, the label and the y-position are extracted from the selected element and put into the annotation text.  Such label can be added via `ax.scatter(..., label=...)`.

(Choosing `'none'` as the color for the "invisible" elements makes them really invisible. To make the code more ["Pythonic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955800/which-is-more-pythonic-in-a-for-loop-zip-or-enumerate) explicit indices can be avoided, working with `zip` instead of with `enumerate`.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import pandas as pd

def show_annotation(sel):
    text = f'{sel.artist.get_label()}\n y={sel.target[1]:.1f}'
    sel.annotation.set_text(text)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Universe': ['Darvel', 'MC', 'MC', 'Darvel', 'MC', 'Other', 'Darvel'],
     'Value': [10, 11, 13, 12, 9, 7, 10],
     'Upper': [12.5, 11.3, 15.4, 12.2, 13.1, 8.8, 11.5],
     'Lower': [4.5, 9.6, 11.8, 6, 6.5, 5, 8]})
df['UpperError'] = df['Upper'] - df['Value']
df['LowerError'] = df['Value'] - df['Lower']

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
all_scatters = []
for universe, color in zip(df['Universe'].unique(), colors):
    to_plot = df[df['Universe'] == universe]
    all_scatters.append(ax.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot['Value'], s=16, c=color, label=universe))
    error = to_plot[['LowerError', 'UpperError']].transpose().to_numpy()
    ax.errorbar(to_plot.index, to_plot['Value'], yerr=error, fmt='o',
                markersize=0, capsize=6, color=color)
    all_scatters.append(ax.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot['Upper'], c='none', zorder=-1, label=universe))
    all_scatters.append(ax.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot['Lower'], c='none', zorder=-1, label=universe))

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(all_scatters, hover=True)
cursor.connect('add', show_annotation)
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors with custom text]

PS: You can also show the `'Universe'` via the x ticks:

```py
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Universe'])
```

If you want to, for short functions you could use the lambda notation instead of writing a separate function:

```py
cursor.connect('add',
               lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(f'{sel.artist.get_label()}\n y={sel.target[1]:.1f}'))
```