# Associate iterables and items from a list in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iterable

Is it possible to associate certain iterables in a loop with certain items from a list ?
I have two lists to start with (`totalpages` and `arguments`) and I need to build up certain URL's.

```
totalpages = [300, 0]
arguments = ['argument1', 'argument2']
urllst = []

for i in totalpages:
  pages = list(range(0, x+100, 100))
  print(pages)
  for page, argument in zip(pages, arguments):
    urls = 'http://URL'+str(page)+argument
    urllst.append(urls)

urllst
```

I would like `urllst` to be like :

```
[
'http://URL0argument1',
'http://URL100argument1',
'http://URL200argument1',
'http://URL300argument1',
'http://URL0argument2'
]
```

Comment: Better zip "totalpages" and "arguments" in outer loop and iterate over "pages" in inner loop.

Comment: Just to clarify, @hug do you want the permutations of the 2 lists pages and arguments, so you can append them to 'http://URL' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write this answer to express my opinion on using index here.

You were very close to the solution, but `zip`'ped wrong lists finally. Here's what should work:

```py
totalpages = [300, 0]
arguments = ['argument1', 'argument2']
urllst = []

for x, argument in zip(totalpages, arguments):
    for page in range(0, x+100, 100):
        url = f'http://URL{page}{argument}'
        urllst.append(url)

print(urllst)
```

This iterates over pairs `(page_number, argument)` made from two initial lists by taking items corresponding to the same indices. I switched to f-string to make string concatenation a bit prettier.

Here's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955800/which-is-more-pythonic-in-a-for-loop-zip-or-enumerate) about comparing index-based, `enumerate`-based and `zip` solutions for such kind of problems.

To ensure that input lists are of equal size, you can use `zip(totalpages, arguments, strict=True)` - this requires python version 3.10 or newer.

Finally, if you're appending in a loop, you're probably missing an optimisation opportunity: list comprehension would be faster, especially on long inputs.

```py
totalpages = [300, 0]
arguments = ['argument1', 'argument2']
urllst = [
    f'http://URL{page}{argument}'
    for x, argument in zip(totalpages, arguments)
    for page in range(0, x+100, 100)
]

print(urllst)
```

Answer (score 1):

With short `zip` (to aggregate elements from each of the iterables) + `itertools.chain.from_iterable` (to treat consecutive inner sequences as a single sequence) approach:

```
import itertools

urllst = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    [f'http://URL{p}{arg}' for p in range(0, page + 100, 100)] 
    for page, arg in zip(totalpages, arguments)))

print(urllst)
```

The output:

```
['http://URL0argument1', 'http://URL100argument1', 'http://URL200argument1', 'http://URL300argument1', 'http://URL0argument2']
```

Comment: Wow, does `itertools.chain` have any advantages over plain listcomp with 2 `for`'s? Never thought of it's usage in such contexts.

Answer (score -1):

Printing pages after it has been instantiated as a list of numbers will not give you the proper output. It is simpler to just go through each number in a modified nested for-loop:

```
totalpages = [300, 0]
arguments = ['argument1', 'argument2']
urllst = []

for i in range(len(totalpages)):
  curr_arg = arguments[i]
  for x in range(0, totalpages[i]+100, 100):
    urls = 'http://URL'+str(x)+curr_arg
    urllst.append(urls)

print(urls)
```

Comment: I downvote, because OP already knows about `zip` and you provide un-pythonic index-based solution. (And this doesn't work at all, you try to access `arguments[300]` on the first step - it should be `for i in range(len(totalpages))` then, and it's **very** ugly)

Comment: @SUTerliakov what is the point of `zip` in this scenario though? `range(len(totalpages))` is a commonly used format. I think `zip` overcomplicates what is otherwise a very simple index-based solution.

Comment: Em, `for x, curr_arg in zip(totalpages, arguments)`, of course, to avoid indexing the lists?.. If you need `something[i]` and `something_else[i]` on every iteration, you cal always use `zip(something, something_else)` instead and throw the `i` index away.

Comment: Related discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955800/which-is-more-pythonic-in-a-for-loop-zip-or-enumerate).

Comment: Yes, but the size of `arguments` is not necessarily the same as `totalpages` because of the restriction that every argument's interval must be added as well. `zip` isn't a necessary addition to this solution and attempting to use it can , arguably, make the code look messier

Comment: If the size is not the same, then the problem is ill-defined. To prevent this from happening, you can use `zip(totalpages, arguments, strict=True)` on python 3.10 and newer.

Comment: But `strict` parameter asserts equal length when that is not the goal of OP's program. Saying the problem is "ill-defined" does not solve it.

Comment: Your code makes also an assumption (that is more 'hidden' than when using `zip`, so I would consider it a bad thing): that `arguments` will be at least as long as `total_pages`. Using indices doesn't help, it just makes things less clear.

Comment: ...so your solution just raises an IndexError, if lengths are different (well, if `arguments` is shorter than `totalpages`, to be strict). `zip(..., strict=True)` raises a `ValueError` in such case. What's the essential difference?